# Get current ClickOnce's application publisher name?

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

Is it possible to read the publisher name of the currently running ClickOnce application (the one you set at `Project Properties -> Publish -> Options -> Publisher name` in Visual Studio)?

The reason why I need it is to run another instance of the currently running application as described in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ExecuteClickOnceApp.aspx) article and pass parameters to it.

Of course I do *know* my application's publisher name, but if I hard code it and later on I decide to change my publisher's name I will most likely forget to update this piece of code.

Comment: In terms of launching your other instance of the ClickOnce app I would use try to use activation URL's with querystring parameters instead if possible within your environment (need to deploy to a webserver). As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588608/clickonce-application-wont-accept-command-line-arguments/7588781#7588781

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to my case. This installs from a server, but doesn't "run" from a server as far as I know. I mean you can run it offline too after installed. Are you just supposed to pass that URL to `Process.Start`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would think this would be trivial, but I don't see anything in the framework that gives you this info.

If you want a hack, you can get the publisher from the registry.

**Disclaimer** - Code is ugly and untested...

```
    ...
    var publisher = GetPublisher("My App Name");
    ...

    public static string GetPublisher(string application)
    {
        using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"))
        {
            var appKey = key.GetSubKeyNames().FirstOrDefault(x => GetValue(key, x, "DisplayName") == application);
            if (appKey == null) { return null; }
            return GetValue(key, appKey, "Publisher");
        }
    }

    private static string GetValue(RegistryKey key, string app, string value)
    {
        using (var subKey = key.OpenSubKey(app))
        {
            if (!subKey.GetValueNames().Contains(value)) { return null; }
            return subKey.GetValue(value).ToString();
        }
    }
```

If you find a better solution, please follow-up.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another option. Note that it will only get the publisher name for the currently running application, which is all I need.

I'm not sure if this is the safest way to parse the XML.

```
public static string GetPublisher()
{
    XDocument xDocument;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext.DeploymentManifestBytes))
    using (XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(memoryStream))
    {
        xDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlTextReader);
    }
    var description = xDocument.Root.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "description").First();
    var publisher = description.Attributes().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "publisher").First();
    return publisher.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about ClickOnce, but normally, you can read the assembly-info using the System.Reflection framework:

```
public string AssemblyCompany
    {
        get
        {
            object[] attributes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute), false);
            if (attributes.Length == 0)
            {
                return "";
            }
            return ((AssemblyCompanyAttribute)attributes[0]).Company;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, theres no "publisher" custom-attribute, just throwing this out as a possible work-around