# Not able to get Application startup path on click on setup.exe

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am publishing a Windows project and on click on form I am installing another setup to install.

I am not getting the current Application Startup Path on clickevent on button.

On debug and Release it is showing the right path but after publishing it is giving

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 path

Already I have used :

```
Application.StartupPath
Application.Executablepath
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase))
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```

But of no use it always show

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 path

Comment: Do you want the .application file path?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that path because it's the one used by ClickOnce. ClickOnce applications are installed under the profile of the user who installed them.

**Edit :**

**Method 1:**

Here's a way to get the path where your application was installed from (works only if your application was installed) (parts of this were written by [@codeConcussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8810355/162671)) :

```
// productName is name you assigned to your app in the 
// Project properties -> Publish -> Publish Settings
public static string GetInstalledFromDir(string productName)
{
    using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"))
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            var appKey = key.GetSubKeyNames().FirstOrDefault(x => GetValue(key, x, "DisplayName") == productName);
            return appKey == null ? null : GetValue(key, appKey, "UrlUpdateInfo");
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private static string GetValue(RegistryKey key, string app, string value)
{
    using (var subKey = key.OpenSubKey(app))
    {
        if (subKey == null || !subKey.GetValueNames().Contains(value)) 
        { 
            return null; 
        }

        return subKey.GetValue(value).ToString();
    }
}
```

Here's how to use it :

```
Uri uri = new Uri(GetInstalledFromDir("ProductName"));
MessageBox.Show(Path.GetDirectoryName(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.AbsolutePath)));
```

**Method 2 :**

You can also try

```
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri
```

But I think this one works only if your app was installed from the internet

Comment: Any way to get the current location of the .exe?

Comment: Well that's because the .exe is in there. You can verify with task manager - select the process and hit properties - you'll see the exe poperties - for chrome it's C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application

Comment: @Nacereddine Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase) would probably be what he wants

Comment: @t3hn00b have used this also but no use

Comment: @user1731023 What's the problem/error/exception you're getting ?

Comment: @Nacereddine: I want to make a CD and have two different setup. I need on click on link get the current location / position so I can install the application accordingly.. There is no error / exception just getting the wrong location / path

Comment: Why - what's wrong with the path? This is the path where the application is located(installed). What path do you expect to get - the location of the ClickOnce application file?

Comment: It is giving C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 path  I want the location where the file resides.. Need the path where the setup resides

Comment: Yeah, but what do you want to get? It is supposed to give that as it's where the application is started from

Comment: @user1731023 you want the path where your application was installed from ? the path of the ClickOnce installer (setup.exe) ?

Comment: @Nacereddine  i want the path where MY application was installed from

Comment: @user1731023 what path do you want to get? That would probably clear things up.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I finally got a way to solve this issue. I had 2 installer in Project and a Project for multiple selection of these 2 installer. I included this two installer link with the Multiple Selection Project and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

BTW, is it ClickOnce deployment? If so then the directory you are getting looks about right.

Comment: Still it is showing the same C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 path